# Social Rabbit - Wordpress Social Media Plugin Setting Auth

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook

I am using Social Rabbit Plugin Wordpress. I have created App in facebook developer account and link it with my website by using app id and secret key and set all url and valid authentication for app and website.Now on clicking Auth in social rabbit plugin wordpress admin section its giving invalid scope publish_action on access token key for App section in developer account i am using App in version v2.12 and i am not getting any way to edit scope of app or permission for app on facebook developer account.In App review section i have added other reviews needed for user permission it is asking for reason to create app and other options,video and all permission requires same submission review is disabled.

[image: Facebook Login error invalid publish action]

[image: App review for all permissions]

[image: Individual app review]

Comment: App review is paused. You have to wait until they open it up again

Comment: How i can add scope to app because i am getting no option on access token section in facebook developer section previously for one app i have added all permission that is required and now it is not possible.

Comment: As I said. You have to wait

Answer (score 0):

Facebook had deprecated publish_action permission. 
https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/04/24/new-facebook-platform-product-changes-policy-updates/